# Show full Image when hover over thumbnail as Popup/Overlay

Tags: java, image, swing, overlay

I display thumbnails in a JPanel. When hovering over such a thumbnail, I want to display its full version in an overlay over the thumbnail.

Using HTML I would just create a div with the proper positions and a high z-index, so that it overlays everything else.
Is something similiar and lightweight possible with Swing?

Comment: make a JFrame: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html; I used to override JComponent and create my own custom popping window

Comment: Or a JWindow which is undecorated.

Comment: I second the JWindow idea, positioned relative to the mouse/thumbnail. That was my initial thought.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I note in an edit to my answer that a `JWindow` is the better solution.  Care to upgrade that comment to an answer so I can express my up-vote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use a tool-tip.

[image: ThumbTip]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

class ThumbTip {

    private static final String HTML = "<html><body>";

    ThumbTip(String[] album) {
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0,2,2));
        for (String url : album) {
            String s = HTML + "<img src='" + url.toString() + "'";
            String size = " width=200 height=150";
            JLabel l = new JLabel(s + size + ">");
            l.setToolTipText(s + ">");
            p.add(l);
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String[] urls = {
            "http://pscode.org/media/stromlo1.jpg",
            "http://pscode.org/media/stromlo2.jpg"
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ThumbTip(urls);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### Note:

1. In this demo. the tool-tip image is downloaded from the net each time it is used.  Be patient.
2. <strike>I did not bother to 'thumbnail' the original images.  'Batteries not included'.</strike>  The latest edit of the source use HTML (the `width`/`height` specified for the `image`) to shrink the 'thumbnails'.  I won't update the screenshot.
3. Ultimately the suggestion of using a `JWindow` is better, since it gives you more  control of where and for how long the pop-up appears, as well as its exact look.  But this hack is significantly shorter.  ;)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  FMI (forgive my ignorance) but what does BNI mean?  I understand the other bits, especially LOL ;)