# What's an easy way to display an Image in Java/Scala?

Tags: java, image, swing, scala

I want to play around with some image manipulation code I'm writing, so I'd like to use the Scala console or something like BlueJ's Java CodePad to create a java.awt.Image and then just pop it up to look at.

Ideally, it'd just be a panel or something without a Frame that would appear and I could just click it to make it disappear. Is there a way to make something that lightweight, or do I really need some kind of frame and more scaffolding?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, new JLabel(new ImageIcon(theImage)));
```

---

Of course, if you have an `URL` for the image (or can form one from a `File` path), it can also be displayed as a tool-tip using HTML.

[image]

See [Show full Image when hover over thumbnail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8965740/418556) for source.

Answer (score 6):

In Scala, use the Java Swing ImageIcon

```
val img = new ImageIcon("path/to/file.jpg")
```

with Scala Swing Dialog

```
Dialog.showMessage(message = img)
```

Or better, display the image instead of the alert icon:

```
Dialog.showMessage(message = null, icon = img)
```